# Solve this system of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Although I have a brief understanding of solving linear ODE systems, I got stuck with this non-linear system:

\begin{align*}
\left(x'(t) \right)^2 + k_1 x + k_1 y = 0\\
\left(y'(t) \right)^2 + k_2 x + k_2 y = 0
\end{align*}
Where $x(0)=x_0$ and $y(0)=y_0$.

It is possible to rewrite this problem to a single equation by eliminating $\partial t$:

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)^2 - \frac{k_1 x + k_1 y}{k_2 x + k_2 y} = 0
\end{align*}

But I don't think this equation is separable.

Can anyone give me some advice or strategy to solve this system?

Comment: The fraction can be simplified to a constant, namely $\frac{k_1}{k_2}$.

Comment: the fraction can become $\sqrt{\frac{k_1}{k_2}}$ and it is solved! tnx

Comment: What about $\pm \sqrt{\frac{k_1}{k_2}}$ ?